# Определить DOCUMENT_ROOT при запуске из консоли

Tags: php, linux, консоль

Есть ли возможность определить константу `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` при запуске скрипта из консоли?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DOCUMENT_ROOT` приходит в php из web-сервера, поэтому в консоли этой информации нет

Comment: То есть, вручную писать глобальные пути в таких скриптах?

Comment: Можно в каком-то конфиге прописать путь до `document root`, например, через `__DIR__`, и во всех скриптах использовать это значение

Answer (score 0):

```
$www_path = realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../'); // тут добавляем "путь наверх", если скрипт не в корне сайта. 
$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] = $www_path;
```